# Detect Viruses in USB?

Tags: linux, debian, usb, gnome-terminal, malware

My USB pen brings often Windows Viruses in it. Before attaching it to windows again I would prefer to delete viruses.

I have Kali Linux. Is there any way to detect Windows viruses/threats through linux(Kali) terminal and delete them ?

Comment: what's a USB virus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use clamav for Linux to scan any disks attached to your system. ClamAV has a graphical front end called ClamTK. It is one of the best well known, it is free and you can install it from the repos.

As for other versions of anti-virus for Linux you can have:

- AVG http://free.avg.com/ww-en/129024
- Comodo https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux
- kaspersky http://www.kaspersky.com/product-updates/linux-file-server-antivirus
- Avast  https://www.avast.com/linux-server-antivirus

Some of them are free, AVAST at least seems to be a paid version for enterprise security.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rui_F_Ribeiro. Can it delete windows viruses from USB

Comment: exactly, otherwise it would not make much sense using an AV.

Comment: @Rui_F_Ribeiro its great if u can help installing it in linux.